# Totalling common factors with maximum factor given

Tags: r, computer-science

The question is:

How to create a function that has two inputs, namely a vector (v) and and integer (n). The output should be the TOTAL value of all values less than or equal to the given integer, which is at least a factor of any one input of the vector.

I started originally by writing

```r
Integer = function(n){
   n_value = sum(0:n)
   Return(n_value)
}
```

I don’t know if this is taking me down the wrong path, however. Any help and guidance would be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can try the code below

```
sum_mult <- function(n, v) sum(seq(n)[rowSums(sapply(v, function(x) seq(n) %% x) == 0) > 0])
```

such that

```
> sum_mult(5, c(2, 3))
[1] 9

> sum_mult(10, c(3, 5))
[1] 33

> sum_mult(100, c(3, 4, 5))
[1] 3046
```

---

**Update**
if you want to count common multiples once or multiple times

```
sum_mult <- function(n, v) sum(sapply(v, function(x) sum(seq(n)[seq(n) %% x==0])))
```

Such that

```
> sum_mult(5, c(2, 3))
[1] 9

> sum_mult(10, c(3, 5))
[1] 33

> sum_mult(100, c(3, 4, 5))
[1] 4033
```

Comment: Shouldn't sum_mult(100, c(3, 4, 5)) print [1] 4033? It works for the others though..

Comment: @HarrisonKeese I don't know if you want to count common multiples once or multiple times. If your desired output is latter case, you should try the update answer.

Comment: I have found upon entering `sum_mult(100, c(2, 4, 6, 11)) as an example, the answer is incorrect. It returns 504211 instead of 272775...

Comment: @HarrisonKeese Do you want to count the common multiple only once or multiple time? It's not clarified in your post. If you try my first solution, it gives `272775`. My second solution gives the same results as the answer you accepted, but you say it is incorrected. I am confused...

Comment: Apologies, the first answer was correct, yet I didn't realise in the question that I wasn't supposed to duplicate common factors. first answer was correct. apologies.

Answer (score 0):

```
Total_sum <- function(n,v){
  
  sum = 0 #initialize a sum variable
  
  for (i in (1:n)){ #take each integer to n 
    
    for (item in v){ #take each item in the input vecto
       
      if (i %% item == 0){ #check if the particular integer (to the n counter) is a multiple of item via the modulo operator
        sum = sum + i #if yes, add it up to the sum
      }
    }
  }
  return(sum)
}
```

Comment: The community encourages adding explanations to questions and not posting purely code answers (see [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300837/what-comment-should-i-add-to-code-only-answers)).

Comment: all the iterations I have tried seem to work, and the signposting in the code helped me understand. Must you have sum = 0 in order to start a summation? Also, is the 'item' purely another variable like 'i', so in essence we don't need to define the vector itself. I think this is where I was wasting time.